# JQuery textbox value computation

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and i am looking for a script which fulfills the below need.

User has to type a number input in the textbox say:456 (Can be input of any length) the value has to change to 000000000000000456 (length has to be 18 with zeros appended in front of the user input).

Eg: 12 has to change to 000000000000000012

145 has to change to 000000000000000145

Function has to be invoked on click of button.
Below is the snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#acb1").click(function () {
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<div>
<input type="text" id="ac1" value=""/>
<input type="button" id="acb1" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript/1267338#1267338

Answer (score 1):

```
function pad(number, length) {
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }

    return str;
}

alert(pad(145, 18));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JavaScript `for` loop to increment zeroes in front of the string until the `variable.length === 18`. Tell me if you need an example. :)

Here is an example (using Manuels function): http://jsfiddle.net/BX5Xs/1/

Comment: Pls help me with an example, also let me know how to avail this function inside JQuery click function in my snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript/1267338#1267338) before. You are wondering how to create a zero-filled String of the number in your input field. This is the proposed function by [Peter Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript/1267338#1267338):

```
function zeroFill( number, width )
{
  width -= number.toString().length;
  if ( width > 0 )
  {
    return new Array( width + (/\./.test( number ) ? 2 : 1) ).join( '0' ) + number;
  }
  return number;
}
```

In your case you can use it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#acb1").click(function () {
         var num = this.value;
         var padded_num = zeroFill(num, 18);
         alert('Zero padded number: ' + padded_num);   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#acb1").click(function () {
  var inp = $('#ac1').val();
  var limit = 18;
  var inpLen = inp.length;
  var res = '';
  for(var i=0;i<(limit-inpLen);i=i+1){
res = res + '0';
  }
  res = res + inp;
});
```

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#acb1").click(function () {
        var len = $("#ac1").val().length;

        if (len < 18 && len > 0)
        {
            var temp = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 18 - len; i++)
            {
                temp += '0';
            }
            temp +=$("#ac1").val();

            $("#ac1").val(temp);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help!!